# Backward propagation - Character Recognizing - Seeking an example

Tags: java, php, python, neural-network

i looking for a example of character recognizing (just one - for example X or A)
using MLP, Backward propagation.

I want a simple example, and not the entire library. Language does not matter, preferably one of those Java, Python, PHP

Answer (score 1):

Support Vector Machines tend to work much better for character recognition with error rates around 2% generally reported. I suggest that as an alternative if you're just using the character recognition as a module in a larger project.